# Adaline Simple Layer Neural Network Class in Python and ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, neural-network

I am not new to (supervised) machine learning, but I am a beginner in PYTHON and specifically in numpy. Following an ebook, I am trying to  define a working example of Adaline NN for a classification task
Starting the full workflow I have imported a dataframe, and selected features and target, split in Train/Test dataframe and defined a Column Transformation strategy

```
df = pd.read_excel("...DOCS_R-ExpFullImpTobaccoAdd_19Feb23.xlsx")

print(f"{y_}Data types of data columns: \n{m_}{df.dtypes}")

df.sample(8, random_state=6).T

df.isnull().sum()

# Define Vectors
num_cols = [
                "age",
                "tm_hospstay",
                "vit_bmi",
                "vit_temp",
                "rf_predmort",
                "rf_preddeep",
                "rf_predreop",
                "rf_meldscr",
                "ech_lveddpre",
                "ech_lvefpre"
                            ]
binary_cols = [
                "sex",
                "hx_afib",
                "hx_arrhythmia",
                "hx_cabg",
                "hx_cad",
                "hx_cancer",
                "rf_tobacco",
                "rf_diab",
                "rf_dyslip",
                "rf_dialysis",
                "rf_htn"
                        ]

cat_cols = [
                "admreasnb",
                "rf_copd"
                            ]

ordin_cols = ["vit_nyha",
              "vit_angccs"] # Ordinal Variables to be encoded

target = df[['out_infx']]

# Recast Categoricals as Integers (Best way of analysis in PYTHON)
for var in cat_cols:
    df[var] = df[var].astype('Int64') # Convert from Category to Float (otherwise the merging does not work)

for var in binary_cols:
    df[var] = df[var].astype('Int64') # Convert from Category to Float (otherwise the merging does not work)

for var in ordin_cols:
    df[var] = df[var].astype('Int64') # Convert from Category to Float (otherwise the merging does not work)

# Recode Target (Any Infection) as 1 and -1 (in place of 1 and 0)
target =  np.where(target==0,-1,1).astype('int')

# Create a Vector of all predictors
features_cols = num_cols + binary_cols + cat_cols + ordin_cols

# Then a Dataframe
features = df[num_cols + binary_cols + cat_cols + ordin_cols]

# Finally create training and testing DataFrames
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=target)

# Setup Column Transformation
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop="first", sparse=False)

standtrans = make_pipeline(OutlierTrans(3),
  SimpleImputer(strategy="median"),
  StandardScaler())
ordintrans = make_pipeline(MakeOrdinal(),
  StandardScaler())
bintrans = make_pipeline(ohe)
cattrans = make_pipeline(ohe)

coltrans = ColumnTransformer(
  transformers=[
    ("stand", standtrans, num_cols),
    ("ord", ordintrans, ordin_cols),
    ("bin", bintrans, binary_cols),
    ("cat", cattrans, cat_cols),
  ]
)
```

I have then used the AdalineGD class I have read about:

```
class AdalineGD(object):
    """ADAptive LInear NEuron classifier.

    Parameters
    ------------
    eta : float
      Learning rate (between 0.0 and 1.0)
    n_iter : int
      Passes over the training dataset.
    random_state : int
      Random number generator seed for random weight
      initialization.


    Attributes
    -----------
    w_ : 1d-array
      Weights after fitting.
    cost_ : list
      Sum-of-squares cost function value in each epoch.

    """
    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=50, random_state=1):
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.random_state = random_state

    def fit(self, X, y):
        """ Fit training data.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like}, shape = [n_examples, n_features]
          Training vectors, where n_examples is the number of examples and
          n_features is the number of features.
        y : array-like, shape = [n_examples]
          Target values.

        Returns
        -------
        self : object

        """
        rgen = np.random.RandomState(self.random_state)
        self.w_ = rgen.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.01, size=1 + X.shape[1])
        self.cost_ = []

        for i in range(self.n_iter):
            net_input = self.net_input(X)
            # Please note that the "activation" method has no effect
            # in the code since it is simply an identity function. We
            # could write `output = self.net_input(X)` directly instead.
            # The purpose of the activation is more conceptual, i.e.,
            # in the case of logistic regression (as we will see later),
            # we could change it to
            # a sigmoid function to implement a logistic regression classifier.
            output = self.activation(net_input)
            errors = (y - output)
            self.w_[1:] += self.eta * X.T.dot(errors)
            self.w_[0] += self.eta * errors.sum()
            cost = (errors**2).sum() / 2.0
            self.cost_.append(cost)
        return self

    def net_input(self, X):
        """Calculate net input"""
        return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]

    def activation(self, X):
        """Compute linear activation"""
        return X

    def predict(self, X):
        """Return class label after unit step"""
        return np.where(self.activation(self.net_input(X)) >= 0.0, 1, -1)
```

Finally trying to put everything together with a pipeline

```
ada = AdalineGD(eta=0.01, n_iter=15)

pipe1 = make_pipeline(coltrans, ada)

for i in tqdm(range(100),  ncols=100, desc="Computation Time"):
pipe1.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Unfortunately, when I try to fit the ada model I get the following error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (34,) (34,3711) (34,)
```

FYI,
X_train.shape --> (3711, 25)
y_train.shape --> (3711, 1)

So I do not understand 34 is coming from
Finally, I have also tried to convert the X_train 2D array in a numpy array
using

```
pipe1.fit(X_train.values, y_train)
```

But then I get another error

```
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

So I am stuck right now, any help and above all a reasonable explanation of what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

Here it is a sample of the X_train dataframe

```
      age  tm_hospstay  vit_bmi  vit_temp  rf_predmort  rf_preddeep  rf_predreop  rf_meldscr  ech_lveddpre  ech_lvefpre  sex  hx_afib  \
20     83          121    26.37     35.00         0.01         0.01         0.06        8.18            46        62.00    1        0   
1438   62          121    30.84     36.00         0.02         0.00         0.03        9.54            60        22.00    0        0   
3346   70           10    24.97     35.00         0.02         0.00         0.04       10.18            46        45.00    1        0   
2196   77           44    20.81     34.00         0.06         0.00         0.04       11.29            39        50.00    1        0   
59     55            7    25.96     36.00         0.02         0.01         0.02        6.40            51        56.30    0        0   
      hx_arrhythmia  hx_cabg  hx_cad  hx_cancer  rf_tobacco  rf_diab  rf_dyslip  rf_dialysis  rf_htn  admreasnb  rf_copd  vit_nyha  vit_angccs  
20                0        0       0          0           0        1          0            0       1          0        0         2           0  
1438              0        0       0          0           0        1          0            0       1          9        2         4           0  
3346              0        0       0          0           0        1          0            0       1          2        0         2           0
```

and of the y_train array

```
array([[-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       ...,
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1]])
```

Hope that can help

Comment: With 34 (?) features/outputs your weights matrix should be more than 1D just fyi, but I can't eyeball the problem with incompatible shapes. Can you provide some example data?

Comment: I would happy to, might you please give me an hint on how to get and post a minimal sample of X_train and y_train ? Sorry for my uselessness in PYTHON

Comment: Ok, I have added a sample of both X_train and y_train, hopefully, the right way

Comment: so the desired responses (y_train?) are -1 and 1? what is the expected classification? binary?  then your weights matrix might be fine.

Comment: Yup it is a binary outcome, coming from a Perceptron example I have recoded tha outcome/target as 1 / - 1 in place of 1 / 0 but that should not make any difference, is that correct ?

Comment: Yup [-1, 1], not [0, 1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed up your `AdalineGD` `class`: your `net_input` should be the `random_sample` selected from the dataset not the `dot` product of the weights, and the `output` and `cost_` weren't correct. I used the first two labels and all four features of the Iris dataset for example (so you can input as many features as your dataset has and predict two output labels of `-1` and `1`), and I included `total_errors` as another measure of performance:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header=None)
df.tail()
_y = df.iloc[:100, 4].values
y = np.zeros((len(_y), 1), dtype=float)
for i in range(len(_y)):
    if _y[i].endswith('setosa'):
        y[i, 0] = 1.0
    elif _y[i].endswith('versicolor'):
        y[i, 0] = -1.0
x = df.iloc[:100, :4].values

class AdalineGD(object):
    def __init__(self, eta, n_iter):
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_iter = n_iter

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.w_ = np.ones(1 + x.shape[1])*0.1
        self.cost_ = []
        self.total_errors = []
        error = 0
        for i in range(self.n_iter):
            random_sample = np.random.randint(len(y))
            net_input = X[random_sample]
            output = self.eta * (y[random_sample] - self.predict(net_input))
            self.w_[1:] += output * net_input
            self.w_[0] += output
            cost = ((y[random_sample] - self.predict(net_input))**2).sum() / 2.0
            error += int(output != 0.0)
            self.cost_.append(cost)
            self.total_errors.append(error)
        return self

    def net_input(self, X):
        """Calculate net input"""
        return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]

    def activation(self, X):
        """Compute linear activation"""
        return X

    def predict(self, X):
        """Return class label after unit step"""
        return np.where(self.activation(self.net_input(X)) >= 0.0, 1.0, -1.0)

ada = AdalineGD(eta=0.01, n_iter=300)
ada.fit(x, y)
plt.plot(ada.total_errors)
plt.plot(ada.cost_)
plt.legend(['total errors', 'cost'], loc='center right')
plt.xlabel('iterations')
plt.show()
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me, but: 1) I do not get why the above reported adaline class does not work for me and my X_train y_train and 2) How eventually  modfy the Adaline class in order to include your suggestion and fix the issue

Comment: If I remember where I've seen that example correctly, it used two input features for binary classification; thus, a 3-D x 1-D flat weight matrix works but if you try to implement anything more complex it fails. So I re-wrote the 'perceptron' code for multiple classification (e.g. Iris dataset).

Comment: All right then, I see. It is a little bit disappointing to have an entire class defined and function for a toy dataset with 2 predictors only only but it is what it is...would you mind to share your perceptron to be applied to a features space > 2, still having a binary target (1 / -1) ? That would be really helpful to me

Comment: Yup, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you  very much, maybe it is not a full answer but at least a practical work-around

Comment: @Diego I fixed up your AdalineGD class to work on the Iris dataset so you should be able to input your dataset with any number of features.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry for my late reply, I have now set this as the correct answer :-)